# gVim Portable plugins

Tags: vim, plugins

Can someone give me a detailed instalation procedure for gVim Portable and important C++ and python development plugins ... like OmniCppComplete, NERDTree, supertab etc ...

or better yet, a prebuilt version

thx

Comment: Did you check the `README`'s for these plugins? To create "plugin packages" check `:help vimball`.

Comment: Also, since I guess almost every plugin is just written in some scripting language, there is no need for "building" them. They just get installed. Maybe you could give more context on what kind of problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: I did, for OmniCppComplete it said to unzip to the .vim directory in your home dir, so I unzipped in the gVim Portable directory, then the Data directory and then the settings directory

I also read on a site that u had to paste some settings in a _vimrc file, I did that

It was about the same for NERDTree, unzip to the so called .vim directory and copy 2 other files

NO LUCK for anyone

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using plugins on portable vim will require slightly different steps than the regular install. From the [configuration](http://portablegvim.sourceforge.net/configuration.html) page, your .vim file should probably be in Data/settings/.vim instead of ~/.vim

Follow the plugin install instructions and substitute ~/.vim with ((where you put PortableGvim))/Data/settings/.vim

If a plugin does an automatic install, then you may need to move files from ~/.vim

---

You may find it easier to grab someone else's vimfiles. [Mine are on github](http://github.com/pydave/daveconfig/tree/master/multi/vim/).

As for the plugins themselves, I got started with [this post](http://www.sontek.net/post/Python-with-a-modular-IDE-(Vim).aspx). See also [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144201/has-anyone-found-a-good-set-of-python-plugins-for-vim-specifically-module-comp).

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, if you can live with there being possible issues if you use a computer with vim installed and vimfiles present in the $HOME directory, you can simply take your `vim72` directory, your `vimfiles` directory and your `_vimrc` (and `_gvimrc` if you have one) and put them in `e:\vim` (assuming `E:` is where the USB stick is mounted).  You can then just run `e:\vim\vim72\gvim.exe` and it will load the configuration from `e:\vim\_vimrc` and `e:\vim\vimfiles`.  If you plug it into a computer that mounts it as `F:`, then just run `f:\vim\vim72\gvim.exe` obviously.

Importantly, this does not require messing about with PortableGvim (which I've never really seen the point of since gvim is essentially portable anyway if you ignore the possible $HOME issues) and allows you to easily synchronise all of your settings between your desktop vim installation and your portable one.

On top of this, I also put vimrc in c:\vim\vimfiles and have _vimrc in c:\vim with the following contents:

```
runtime vimrc
```

and then put the whole of c:\vim\vimfiles under version control.  This makes it very easy to keep the copy on the USB stick and the copy on the Windows PC (and the copy on my home Linux PC and... and...) synchronised.